# Inline edit in vue js 3 with Composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inline-editing

I tried to make inline editing in `Vue Js 3` with `Composition API`and I face this problem. When I click `edit`, it impacts all rows. How do I make it to only work in one row based on `id`?

[Here's the result I have so far](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

The codes are there, but if it needs to be posted here as well, I will edit this question to put it here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches for this:

1. Create a component for each row and manage its `togel` state within the component.
2. Make `togel` variable a map in the form: `{ [id]: true/false }`. Then each `togel[id]` would be responsible for its own row state. [Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Approach #1 is a more straight-forward way.

Comment: the second approach is easier for me. thank you.